# Fastest method to find A[not slice] for a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, slice

What is the fastest way to access the values that are at the opposite of a particular given slice? Some code:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(2,100000)
S = slice(79,78954,34)
A[S] #This is all the values I do NOT want. 
A[?] #All the values I want are the values in A but not in A[S], what is ?.
```

Comment: Is it not just ```A[~np.array(range(79,78954,34))]```? I think slice works in a similar fashion to the range function and you can use numpy arrays to index other numpy arrays.

Comment: `np.delete` does this by creating boolean mask that selects the values you want to keep.

Comment: @hpaulj fantastic, thanks, did you want credit?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use masked arrays:

```
A = np.ma.array(A)
A[S] = np.ma.masked
A.compressed()
```